# Not able to install maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I am not able to install the maven in eclipse. I have tried to install from 
"http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases" URL

I am getting the below error.

```
 Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be   found.
 Software being installed: m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.5.2.20150413-2215 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group 1.5.2.20150413-2215)
  Missing requirement: m2e logback configuration 1.5.2.20150413-2215 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration 1.5.2.20150413-2215) requires 'bundle ch.qos.logback.slf4j 0.9.24' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
   From: m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.5.2.20150413-2215 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group 1.5.2.20150413-2215)
To: org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration [1.5.2.20150413-2215]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem, and found working solution on the Internet. It goes as follows:

```
Help->Install New Software->Add
    Name: slf4j
    Location: http://www.fuin.org/p2-repository/

    choose Maven osgi-bundles->slf4j-api
```

install, restart eclipse. It should be ok at this step.

In my case, I had to install 2 more dependencies, but I think it is not necessary in your case (unless you are trying to integrate Maven with RTC Client as well - I can send you step by step solution then ;-) )